# How to hit the controller from JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and a Jquery. I want to hit the controller from JQuery. But I am unable to hit the controller. Please suggest me where I am getting wrong and what are the extra things needed to hit the controller.

This line of code gives me error `$(this).load(raceId);`

> GET http://localhost:53987/Races/RacesName?id=103646584 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

Controller

```
public ActionResult RacesName(int race)
{
  ClsRaces clsRaces = new ClsRaces();
   race = clsRaces.RaceId;
    return View();
}
```

Script

```
  var race = $(this).data("raceid");
  var raceId = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Races")?id=' + race;
  $(this).load(raceId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method has a parameter named `int race` but you are not sending a name/value pair for `race` (what you are sending is one for a parameter named `id`)

Either change the script to

```
var raceId = '@Url.Action("RacesName", "Races")?race=' + race;
```

**OR**

change the controller method to

```
public ActionResult RacesName(int id)
```

As a side note, you can use you browser tools (the Network tab) to inspect the response which will include the details of the exception that is being thrown (which in you case was that a value was not provided for the `race` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can do this in many ways.

1) The best way I suggest is to write ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Races/RacesName',
    dataType: 'text',
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    data: {
        race: race   
    },
    success: function (data) {                          
      console.log('Success');
      // Perform any action you would like to do.
      // If you want to redirect to some other controller or method
         // window.location.href= '/Races/Racedetails'
      // If you want to perform UI actions
         // $(.selector).hide();  $(.selector).show(); 
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error occured');
        // Taking care of error // handle exceptions or errors
    }
});
```

2) Directly you can use `window.location.href`

```
  window.location.href = '/Races/RacesName?race='+ race;
   // This method can only redirect to respective controller action method. But further control will not be in our hands.
```